# Android and IOS Fingerprint APIs

Tags: android, ios, fingerprint

I've been reading documentation that Android and IOS's fingerprint scanning API stores the user's encrypted fingerprint locally. Is it possible to build an application that captures the user's fingerprint, encrypt it like a password and store it in the cloud?

If this isn't possible, are there any suggested workarounds people have explored in the past?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get this info out of the device. All you're able to do is validate whether the fingerprint provided by the user matches one that's enrolled in the device. It's basically binary. The finger is recognized or not.

Typically what you want to do is store some kind of generated token in Keychain or other secure storage; after the user locally authenticates with their fingerprint, you use that stored token to authenticate the user with your server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Matt! Just to clarify, based on your response, I won't be able to design an app that leverages the hardware to capture the fingerprint data via my app and store that data on a hosted server to be used for other authentication purposes?

Comment: That is correct, fingerprint data never leaves the phone. You're limited to asking a yes or no question, basically.